# TemplateSyntaxError at /notes/list/ add requires 2 arguments, 1 provided

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying add pagination in my notes list but i am having an 2 argument error. I don't know to fix it. Can you guys tell me how can I solve it?

notes/views.py

```
class NotesListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = '/accounts/login/'
    model = Notes
    context_object_name = 'notes_data'
    paginate_by = 3
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Notes.objects.filter(create_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-create_date')
```

notes/notes_list.html

```
{% if is_paginated %}
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a class ='btn btn-warning'href='?page=1'>first</a>
            <a class ='btn btn-warning'href="?page={{page_obj.previous_page_number}}">Previous</a>   
        {% endif %}
        
        {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
            {% if num == page_obj.number  %}
                <a class ='btn btn-warning'href="?page={{num}}">{{num}}</a>
            {% elif num > page_obj.number|add: '-1' and num < page_obj.number|add: '1' %}
                <a class ='btn btn-success'href="?page={{num}}">{{num}}</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a class ='btn btn-warning'href="?page={{page_obj.next_page_number}}">Next</a>
            <a class ='btn btn-warning'href="?page={{page_obj.paginator.num_pages}}">Last</a>   
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove spaces between add: and '1'

```
page_obj.number|add: '-1' and num < page_obj.number|add: '1'


page_obj.number|add:'-1' and num < page_obj.number|add:'1'
```